# IBAction causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, ibaction

I am writing a project for iOS in swift using the DJI Mobile SDK and the UXSDK sample application (found here: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS).

I added a ViewController with an IBAction getData(_ sender:) which sends a message successfully to a DJI product. When the IBAction completes, the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in AppDelegate.swift

Error flag in AppDelegate
[image: Error flag in AppDelegate]

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

//To use DJI Bridge app, change `useBridge` to true and add bridge app 
IP address in `debugID`
let useBridge = false
let debugIP = "BRIDGE_APP_IP_ADDRESS_HERE"


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, 
UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

open var productCommunicationManager = ProductCommunicationManager()
open var communicationsViewController = CommunicationsViewController()
open var osdkDevice:OnboardSDKDevice?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Start the registration at the launch of the app. This can be retriggered at anytime from the main view.
    // DJI App key needs to be registered in the Info.plist before calling this method.
    self.productCommunicationManager.registerWithProduct()
    return true
    }

}
```

Here is the view controller. It isn't the main one, but it is navigated to through the main view controller.

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import DJISDK
    import DJIUXSDK

    class CommunicationsViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    //This is instantiated as a UIViewController as soon as app launches
    //The reference in appDelegate is reassigned every time the view launches

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var DataDisplay: UITextView!
    open weak var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    //MARK: Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        appDelegate?.communicationsViewController = self
        appDelegate?.productCommunicationManager.connectToProduct()
        appDelegate?.productCommunicationManager.connectedProduct = DJISDKManager.product()
        if (appDelegate?.productCommunicationManager.connectedProduct?.model != nil){
            self.DataDisplay.text = (appDelegate?.productCommunicationManager.connectedProduct.model)
        }
        appDelegate?.osdkDevice = OnboardSDKDevice()
        appDelegate?.osdkDevice?.delegate = appDelegate?.osdkDevice

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func back(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func getData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Create 4 bytes of 0's
        let data = Data(count: 4)
        appDelegate?.osdkDevice?.sendDataFromMobile(toOnboard: data, withCompletion: nil)
        //App crashes after exiting scope
    }

}
```

I have found that EXC_BAD_ACCESS is caused by trying to access memory that is no longer available. I have double checked the connections of all my IBActions and IBOutlets and they seem to be okay.

This is the error message from "bt" in the console
[image: This is the error message from "bt" in the console]

Console and assembly from exception breakpoint
[image: Console and assembly from exception breakpoint]

Could somebody help me diagnose the crash?
iOS programming and Swift are both pretty new to me, so if there anything missing in this description please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint. It provides more specific information about the exception. I guess the reason of the error is `CommunicationsViewController()` which does **not** return the controller in Interface Builder. That means the outlet is not connected and you get the most famous Swift error.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that's what you wanted to see? Which outlet do you mean isn't connected?

Comment: I changed the communicationViewController property to optional and set its value each time I went into that view controller, but am still getting the same error. I'm not trying to exit the view controller through the action but it seems like its deallocating the view controller anyways. I just want to call a method when I hit a button in that view controller